# Flutter web socket example app does not connect to local NestJS server

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, websocket, nestjs

I am trying to get the [Flutter web socket example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets) to work when pointing it to my local NestJS server from within an Android emulator. Here are the different things I have tried:

NestJS server is running on http://127.0.0.1:3000

`IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org')` - This works fine but not my server.

`IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://10.0.2.2:3000')` - Does not work. Ip that maps from Android emulator to localhost on my laptop. Gets the following error: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://10.0.2.2:3000

`IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.1.16:3000')` - Does not work. 192.168.1.16 is the IP of my laptop. Gets the following error: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://192.168.1.16:3000

I have also tried different emulators and different Android versions. It happens on Android emulator, iOS simulator and on an actual iPhone attached to Xcode. I have searched this site and others without any luck. The only solution I have not tried is to put my NestJS server on another machine or in the cloud and create a subdomain to point to it. I have also implemented request logging on my NestJS server and I never see any activity coming from the Flutter app. I can get to my server fine from by browser and the web socket implementation on the server is working. Makes me think it is some sort of a networking problem.

I have also played around with the constructor arguments:

IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.1.16:3000', protocols: ['websocket'])

Not sure how to use the protocols argument, Websocket, websocket, websockets, etc. Not sure if I should be seeing an HttpException or a SocketException.

How do you connect to a local server based on the Flutter web socket example? I need to be able to debug and test this app.

UPDATED:

Just adding some more info here. I wrote a small console program to try and isolate it.

This code works:

```
    void main() { 
          var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org');
          channel.stream.listen((message) {
             print('message: $message');
          }); 
          channel.sink.add('connected!'); 
   }
```

This code does not:

```
    void main() { 
          var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.1.16:3000');
          channel.stream.listen((message) {
             print('message: $message');
          }); 
          channel.sink.add('connected!'); 
   }
```

Here is the stack trace from the code that did not work. ws://echo.websocket.org is a test WebSocket echo site on the internet and 192.168.1.16:3000 is a NestJs WebSocket node server (that does work from a web page client using socket.io) running local on my laptop to where this client code was ran. This code was ran straight from the console without any devices or emulators with the command "dart ./websoket.dart". I think you can rule out the emulators, iOS, and Android.

```
Unhandled exception:
WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://192.168.1.16:3000
#0 new IOWebSocketChannel._withoutSocket. (package:web_socket_channel/io.dart:84:24)
#1 _invokeErrorHandler (dart:async/async_error.dart:16:24)
#2 _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:282:9)
#3 _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:161:13)
#4 _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1396:10)
#5 _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:15)
#6 _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:16)
#7 _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:294:7)
#8 _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:812:19)
#9 _StreamController._addError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:690:7)
#10 _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1396:10)
#11 _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:15)
#12 _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:16)
#13 _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:294:7)
#14 _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:812:19)
#15 _StreamController._addError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:690:7)
#16 new Stream.fromFuture. (dart:async/stream.dart:178:18)
#17 _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1455:54)
#18 _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:157:20)
#19 Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
#20 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
#21 Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
#22 Future._asyncCompleteError. (dart:async/future_impl.dart:593:7)
#23 _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#24 _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#25 _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#26 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

- Thanks

Comment: Ok, I did another test. I located my websocket server in the cloud instead of on my laptop. I am still getting the same error. So it looks like the server I have is terminating the connection. I believe it may be the difference between a true websocket server and a server pretending to be one. I think there are two implementations in the web_socket_channel package. IOWebSocketChannel and HtmlWebSocketChannel. I will try HtmlWebSocketChannel and see how that goes. It is not Flutter, the emulators, iOS, Android or networking. I believe it is a client server mismatch.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any hint?

Comment: @Warren tell us about your experience with HtmlWebSocketChannel?

Comment: Is anyone here using any proxy server?